# When I block an ip address in my .htaccess file, all ip addresses are blocked

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, apache2

I have the following in my .htaccess file in my /var/www on my Ubuntu 14 Wordpress install.

```
order allow,deny
deny from 123.45.6.7
allow from all
```

However, when I browse to the website I get internal server error 500. It seems that all ip addresses are being blocked, not just the one I specified.

Answer (score 3):

In earlier versions of Apache, you can simplify everything to:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 123.45.6.7
```

However, these directives are deprecated in Apache 2.4. Instead, you should use:

```
Require all granted
Require not ip 123.45.6.7
```

Read more in [the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html).